# Python TypeError: Unhashable type when inheriting from subclass with __hash__

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a base class and a subclass, such as:

```py
class Base:
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.x == other.x
    def __hash__(self):
        return hash(self.x)

class Subclass(Base):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        super().__init__(x)
        self.y = y
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.x == other.x and self.y == other.y
```

Since the parent class implements `__hash__`, it should be hashable. However, when I try to put two copies in a set, such as `{Subclass(1, 2), Subclass(1, 3)}`, I get this error:

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'Subclass'
```

I know if an object implements `__eq__` but not `__hash__` then it throws the TypeError, but there is a clearly implemented hash function. What's going on?

Answer (score 2):

The `__eq__` rule applies both to classes without any subclasses implementing `__hash__` and to classes that have a parent class with a hash function. If a class overrides `__eq__`, it *must* override `__hash__` alongside it.

To fix your sample:

```py
class Base:
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.x == other.x
    def __hash__(self):
        return hash(self.x)

class Subclass(Base):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        super().__init__(x)
        self.y = y
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.x == other.x and self.y == other.y
    def __hash__(self):
        return hash((self.x, self.y))
```